# Inaccurate GPS location

Tags: technical-issues, ingress

My phone doesn't have very good gps and sometimes I find myself x meters away from location where I actually am. I'm usually using the phone data connection to Internet and when I can I turn WiFi on. I'm also using one application to get extra gps data.

**How can I make my position in game to be all time accurate even when I have bad quality gps?**

Comment: I don't think we can really answer if it's cheating or not; only the developers can, and they usually do it by banning you.

Comment: @Frank Ok, I will try to rephrase the question to make it maybe answerable.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's pretty much impossible to get an all time accurate location. There are many factors that will degrade the the accuracy and if one is the gps receiver of your phone then there is not much you can do.

- Get a clear view to the sky to obtain better satellite signals.
- Turn on WiFi.  Even if you are using your cellular data provider you can turn WiFi on to get a more accurate location when WiFi access points are around.  Thanks to google magic the location of nearly every access point has been recorded and is being used to triangulate your position.
- Get an external GPS receiver and hook it up to your phone (bluetooth most likely, USB options might be available).  But it's more economical to purchase a new phone.
- Purchase a new phone with a better GPS receiver.

Note that some locations you won't ever have good GPS reception since you need a somewhat unobstructed view of the satellites to receive their signals.  So for example you won't ever have a good location by the artwork in the underground Atlanta airport walkway between the terminals.

Comment: I actually was switching my WiFi on sometimes and sometimes it helps and other times it bugs the location even more :D..(with radar disabled ofc)

Comment: Do you know anyone using the external GPS receiver? I'm just wondering if it's bearable to walk around with 2 devices in your hand/s :D

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it's unethical to go on playing if you jump around and reach to points where you aren't at. You should answer that part yourself. It all comes back to your personality, your morality and your principles in life.

The technical part has already been answered by Claus. I can only add to it that it is very hard in this era to have a bad GPS reception. You always have the option of turning on wifi. If you're complaining about battery drainage then you should remember that nearly all serious ingress players do carry a battery pack with them. You should acquire one, too.

I, myself experience bad reception from time to time (very rarely) and when I experience it, I don't abuse it. I stop playing and go on my way.

Comment: The thing is that mostly it's abusing me than giving me better location. I'm standing on portal IRL and in game I'm still out of range. So I have to stand there x mins or restart app/phone.. so I rather walk away too. It just sucks when I'm rarely at and I can't do a thing without waiting few mins there.

Answer (score 1):

If you think correctly all settings are correct, this is done automatically shows the position becomes clear, especially huge impact location detection using WiFi contained environment also